# How much memory does monerod take on a Ubuntu server?

Tags: monerod, daemon, ubuntu

I'm planning to run a `monerod` node on my Ubuntu server, but I also have a web server running there and another cryptonote daemon. I was wondering, how much memory does `monerod` take on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked on ubuntu and it appears to use 1.1g:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                     
50878 root      20   0   26.6g   1.1g 171644 S   0.7  56.0  74:35.46 monerod
```

Answer (score 1):

On one of my boxes, `monerod` is using 1.2GB RAM, and on another 2GB. Both of these are Ubuntu. Of course, you'll also need a hard disk, ideally SSD, with 30GB+ free for a pruned node or 80GB+ for an unpruned node.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running up to 3 monero daemon's on an very old laptop. 2 GB RAM, 240 GB SSD.
Plus 3 heavy Nodejs apps, Apache, MySQL, MongoDB, Redis and sendmail.

Once a daemon is synced, the CPU and RAM usage is very little.

`Linux Kernel 4.4.182 #1 SMP x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T8100 @ 2.10GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 1.75 GB.

```
$ docker stats

CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
59cba0501edf        monerod             1.61%               1.751GiB / 15.54GiB   11.27%              81.2GB / 421GB      136GB / 224MB       25
```

This particular invocation has been up for about 4 weeks, since I last needed to reboot the kernel. (I've set Docker up to restart the process on boot)